# App icon is not displayed on the simulator screen

Tags: objective-c, xcode, icons, interface-builder, ios-simulator

I draged all kinds of icons. After that I can see them in small windows in "General - App Icons" but when I run a simulator and go to Home Screen, my app icon is not displayed. What is wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Delete the app and re-install from Xcode

Comment: When you say your app icon doesn't appear do you mean that the image that you are using doesn't appear? Or that there is just no icon at all? If it is that the image doesn't appear there is a few things we need to know. 1) What iOS are you running in? 2) What app icons do you have set in your project? 3) What have you already tried?

Comment: The image that I am using doesn't appear. I'v tried to run all iOS versions, because I have all kinds of icons for all resolutions and iOS versions.

Closing,deleting,re-installing,cleaning - nothing helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click "Clean" in Xcode. Then remove app from simulator. Then run app.

Answer (score 1):

restart your simulator. Make sure you have proper icon for device type / resolution you are trying to simulate.

Comment: If there was a wrong type/ resolution, xcode would notify abaut issue

Comment: are you just rebuilding the app and running on simulator? I had this issue in the past and the only thing that helped me was to restart xcode/sim.

Answer (score 1):

For XCode 8 I had this same problem. I had created multiple targets and in doing so had unknowingly removed all targets from membership of Assets.xcassets.

To fix it for me, I selected Assets.xcassets in the project view and then reselected all the targets that I wanted to apply my icon sets to.

[image]